# Why are my global variables being re-initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I will elaborate, I am setting some flags (below) as global variables so that I may use them throughout the C# program. I run debug and it seems everytime the page reloads or the Page_Load routine runs, the global variables are reinitialized. why, and how can I prevent this?

```
  public partial class MakePayment1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        Queries Q = new Queries();
        decimal nopmt;
        decimal nopymts2;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string autopay;
        string ppol;
        string whydt;
        string ccEnd;
        string pmtType;
        bool credCard;
        bool nwCard;
        bool today;
        bool fdate;
        bool dueToday;
        bool dueTime;
        bool expTime;
        SessionVars SV = new SessionVars();
        string nxtpaymnt = "";
        string nxtpaymntDt = "";
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadPageData();
                getContractInfo();
```

Comment: They don't look like global variables.

Comment: they were, I took the initialization out because I thought that was the issue.

Comment: As shown, they are member variables. They are associated with each instance of the class that's created, and a new instance is created every page load.

Comment: got it, I will use session parameters instead. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

C# doesn't have actual global variables. Perhaps you mean static variables? If so, you should say static variables instead to reduce confusion.

The control is recreated each time the page loads. So you have to persist that data somewhere. Usually in a control, the best way to persist data between requests is in ViewState.

If you want to persist some data, you have to make use of [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx), [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/94xkskdf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), local files, or database, etc. When the control loads, retrieve the data.

I'll caution you against using anything besides ViewState in a control: often in a control you may have two tabs open with the control. You may not want the data from those intermingling as it could confuse the user. Since ViewState is stored directly on the page, there's no worry about it intermingling.

Comment: that is what I thought ... thank you!! this will help considerably.

Comment: +1. Side note: "C# doesn't have global variables." - while correct form strictly syntax point of view, this statement may not reflect everyone's meaning of "global variable" - `static` fields/properties are "global variable" in common sense.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov True. I made my strongly worded statement to give him pause. I would urge anyone that uses the term "global variable" in C# to discontinue using that term. Static is both more correct and just as easy to say.